# Is there a way to automatically create CRUD for EF Model (DB First currently)

Tags: c#, wpf, sqlite, entity-framework-6

I am creating a WPF app and I have an existing DB that I would like to use and NOT recreate. I will if I have to, but I would rather not. The DB Is sqlite and when I add it to my data later and create a DataModel based on the DB, I get the model and the DB Context, however there are no methods created for CRUD or for instance .ToList() so I can return all of the items on the table.

Do I need to create all of these manually or is there a way to do it like the way that MVC can scaffold?

I am using VS 2017, WPF, EF6 and Sqlite installed with Nu-Get

Comment: Sounds like you need to read up on Entity Framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer the question in the title.

No.

There is no click-a-button method of scaffolding out UI like you get with MVC.

If you just deal with a table at a time then you could build a generic repository that returns a List for a given table.  That won't save you much coding, but you could do it.

If you made that return an iQueryable rather than just a List then you could "chain" such a query. Linq queries aren't turned into SQL until you force iteration and you can base one on another adding criteria, what to select etc etc for flexibility.

In the body of your post you ask about methods to read and write data.  This seems to be almost totally unrelated from the other question because it's data access rather than UI.

"there are no methods created for CRUD or for instance .ToList() so I can return all of the items on the table."

There are methods available in the form of LINQ extension methods.
ToList() is one of these, except it is usual to use async await and ToListAsync.

Where and Select are other extension methods.

You would be writing any model layer that exposed the results of those though.

I'm not clear whether you are just unaware of linq or what, but here's an example query.

```
        var customers = await (from c in db.Customers
                               orderby c.CustomerName
                               select c)
                               .Include(x => x.Orders) //.Include("Orders") alternate syntax
                               .ToListAsync();
```

EF uses "lazy loading" of related entities, that Include makes it read the Orders for each customer.

Answer (score 1):

**Entity Framework is an Object Relational Mapper**

Which means it will Map your C# objects to Tables.

Whenever you are creating a model from bd it will create a `Context` Class which will in inherit the `DbContext`. in this class you will find all the tables in `DbSet<Tablename> Tablename{get; set;}`. Basically, this list contains will the rows. the operation performed on this list will affect the DB on `SaveChange` method.

> Example for CURD

```
    public DbSet<Student> Students { get; set; }
    //Create
        using (var context = new YourDataContext()) {

          var std = new Student()
           {
              Name = "Aviansh"
            };

             context.Students.Add(std);
             context.SaveChanges();
                    }//Basically saving it will add a row in student table with name field as avinash 

//Delete

     using (var context = new YourDataContext()) {

        var CurrentStudent=context.Students.FirstOrDefault(x=>x.Name=="Avinash")
        CurrentStudent.context.Students.Remove(CurrentStudent);
        context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Note: on `SaveChanges` the change will reflect on Db